# How to open a bootstrap panel based on if conditions(Selection is done using dropdown) using laravel?

Tags: html, laravel-5.4

**I have used a  dropdown snippet. Based on the selection value different panel should pop out.**

Comment: Do you mean the bootstrap 3 panel class, or are you trying to open a modal?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 panel class Sir!!

Answer (score 0):

Read about collapsible elements first:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Read through the documentation on modals and how to interact with them as they are a good reference for using data attributes:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

You can open them using `data` attributes only on html elements which target an element's id, or for your needs, I would bind to the dropdown's `onchange` event and trigger the panels display using JavaScript. A simple function to illustrate:

```
$('#mydropdown').on('change', function () {
    $('#' + $(this).data('target').val() ).toggle('collapse');
});
```

where your dropdown may look like:

```
<select id="mydropdown">
    <option data-target="panel1">panel 1</option>
    <option data-target="panel2">panel 2</option>
    <option data-target="panel3">panel 3</option>
</select>
```

Then one panel may be:

```
<div class="panel panel-default collapse" id="panel1">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Basic panel example
  </div>
</div>
```

That's a very simplified overview but should get you started down the right path. I'm sure you could achieve all this without the using of JavaScript if you desired.